# C# Razor foreach loop syntax in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I got the following javascript code from google chart:

```
function drawTimeChart() {
    var dataArray = generateTimeChartArray();
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['2001', '25'],
      ['2002', 35],
      ['2003', 25],
      ['2004', 55]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Reported devices in MAUDE based on the term since 1990',
        backgroundColor: '#EFEEEF',
        hAxis: { showTextEvery: 4 }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('MaudeTimeChart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The data that I insert into data i want to be dynamicly added. I tried doing like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                @foreach (var item in Model.NumberOfReportedRecords){
                    [@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.year), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)]
                 }
                ]);
```

Anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use [Html.DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407420%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) as it will render template instead of just value. Use simply `@item.year` for getting that value like:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                @foreach (var item in Model.NumberOfReportedRecords){
                    ['@item.year', '@item.Status']
                 }
                ]);
```

**Update 1.**

Also I have some doubts about how you defined foreach loop - it might not work but you can also try something like that (`@:` [explicitly indicates the start of content](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.NumberOfReportedRecords) 
        {
            @:['@(item.year)', '@(item.Status)'],
        }
```

Comment: you should also look at [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914(v=vs.110).aspx) to sanitize the output

Comment: Thanks! This is what i thought as well. But when i write this i get a bunch of errors saying "; expected", "Invalid expression term ,", "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" Got any clue? While if i leave the foreach loop empty or insert the values manually like [2014, 15] no error is displayed

Comment: Than you very much! The last update fixed the problem! @: was the thing I was looking for :)